# AveDesktopSites 2.0 Not working

Tags: windows

Unfortunately I have experienced trouble running AveDesktopSites on Windows 7/8 x64.

The program is running and it's loading the URL, but it only shows it in a little square in the program window - it never goes to the desktop as supposed.

Any suggestions on how to get this program to work will be appreciated!

I have asked for alternative programs on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/software-to-put-company-specific-info-on-the-desktop) but this question is separate and is specifically about fixing AveDesktopSites

Fortunately I was able to find some other people with similar symptoms on the [HowtoGeek Forums](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0ZwH2Ad4nE8J:www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/avedesktopsites-no-errors-but-nothing-happens-+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=bg&client=safari) but unfortunately as it says on the very bottom - it doesn't support x64 bit operating systems.

I tried all the solutions they have discussed there - set a solid background, non-solid background.

On [Aves website](https://web.archive.org/web/20090208132742/http://mpj.tomaatnet.nl/vista) they say that the computer have to to make sure we have  Visual Studio 2005 SP1 Runtime Files, so I tried that as well.

And the last think I remembered I could try was the Compatibility mode, so I set the application to be opened as Windows XP SP2, Windows Vista and Windows Vista SP2 compatibility and it worked just as I have explained above on the top.

Any other solutions/recommendations guys?

Comment: We don't do cross posting across Stackexchange websites.  **I am a little confused why a question that was here at Superuser was migrated to a beta SE website I thought that also didn't happen**

Comment: Unfortunately I have no actual answer on your question. I am confused way much more than you are. There were a number of unknown reasons for that, but at least the thread is still ON.  Now here I am looking for totally different solution and hopefully soon I will get one.

Comment: @Ramhound moderators can migrate to any site when certain criteria are met. The question should be of very high quality for the target site (it was), it should also be a new question (within last day or two), and it should be definitely off topic here (it was). **This** question is very specific and can be seen to be separate from his product recommendation so should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: @Mokubai - Understandable :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the links you posted, the author claims the software does not work on 64-bit operating systems, [as of 2008-02-06](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0ZwH2Ad4nE8J:www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/avedesktopsites-no-errors-but-nothing-happens-%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=bg&client=safari). As you are running a 64-bit version of either Windows 7 or Windows 8, it will not work for you.

If you are a software developer, the source code is available. Exactly how to fix it so it works on a 64-bit version of Windows, if even possible, is well outside the scope of superuser.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see the developer's source code anywhere. Could you please navigate me as you have seen it. 
I will do my best to run it on x64.

Comment: Source code is available on http://www.aveapps.com/avedesktopsites.html, the direct link is http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/AveDesktopSitesSource.zip

Comment: Thanks so much, I must've missed it somehow. Greatly appreciated Chris! ^_^